# Why does streamlit effect Keras callback code?

Tags: deep-learning, keras, image-classification

I use Streamlit for an image classification project in Keras. I defined a lambda callback:

```
def batch_begin(batch, logs):
    st.write(logs)
    if stop_training:
        model.stop_training = True

testmodelcb = LambdaCallback(on_batch_begin=batch_begin)
```

I use `stop_training` parameter to stop training when a button is pressed.

```
    if st.button('Stop training!'):
        stop_training = True
```

Problem is this: When I remove the `st.write(logs)` line, callback does not work.